# How to create a SQL Select-resultset with input parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameters, stored-functions

I have some trouble developing a solution for my customer based resultset in MySQL. Imagine I have some master data and some customer specific (financial) variables. I would like to create a view for the data with a calculated column that is specific to the customer variables.

For example: Master Data Products with price, Customer table with financial input parameters like personal discount, interest rate and financial running time. I created a customer specific finance plan with a recursive cte by creating a stored procedure.

Now I would like to have a result set of products with a column that specifies the price with customer data (complex calculation incl. avg interest rate and running time). I would like to create a Select resultset that I can use in queries as resultset for a website or analytics.

The Problem:

- MySQL stored functions do not return tables -> no function
- MySQL stored procedures can not be embedded into views -> procedure can not be filtered further (Select * from (call procedure) where "more filters")
- MySQL views can not contain parameters or variables (input which customer is currently viewed)

How may a solution look like? I have no more ideas. Thank you for your help.

```html
Set @interestrate = (select ... where customer = @INPUT)
Set @runtime = (select ... where customer = @INPUT)

Select
  productid,
  price,
  (
    price * avg(recursive cte @interestrate, @runtime) * @runtime
  ) as calculation 
from masterdata
where
  criterium_a = "abc"
  criterium_b = "def"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a temporary table:

```
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Cust_Rates;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Cust_Rates AS
        SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Customer = @Input
```

Then `SELECT FROM Cust_Rates` in your query.